# Missing query data when using Sum

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relationship

My database in Microsoft Access looks like this:

[image: Client: CL-ID, CL-Name | Assistant: AS-ID, AS-Name, AS-Client(foregin key), AS-Nice]

- Every `Client` can have many assistants.
- Every `Assistant` may have one client or no clients at all.

Assistant have a `Nice` field which is `Boolean`, indicating whether the Assistant is nice.

I need a query where I can get all of the clients, together with a boolean value indicating whether they have **at least one nice assistant**.

Currently this is the query I have:

[image]

This query is working as you can see: (apperantly `0` is false and `-1` is true)

[image: working!]

#### But here is the problem:

If there is a Client with no Assistants at all, it will not show up in the query.

[image: Every Client have at least one Assistant, except Shoshi.]

[image: Shoshi is not in the query!]

I am wondering if there is a way to add all of the Clients with no Assistant to the query and their `MinOfAS-Nice` column will be `0`. I will also accept any other creative way for example creating another query - but in the end I’m going to need a one query with all of the Clients data.

I need this data for a Report I'm going to create in Access.

Thanks in advance!

GitHub repo: https://github.com/orihpt/MissingRecordsInQueryAccessIssue

For your convinience here is the query as SQL query:

```
SELECT Client.[CL-ID], Client.[CL-Name], Min(Assistant.[AS-Nice]) AS [MinOfAS-Nice]
FROM Client INNER JOIN Assistant ON Client.[CL-ID] = Assistant.[AS-Client]
GROUP BY Client.[CL-ID], Client.[CL-Name]
ORDER BY Client.[CL-ID];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *Left Join*:

```sql
SELECT Client.[CL-ID], Client.[CL-Name], Min(Nz(Assistant.[AS-Nice], 0)) AS [MinOfAS-Nice]
FROM Client LEFT JOIN Assistant ON Client.[CL-ID] = Assistant.[AS-Client]
GROUP BY Client.[CL-ID], Client.[CL-Name]
ORDER BY Client.[CL-ID];
```

Also: the `Nz` function is a default operator, means that on records without any linked records on the another table you will get `0` instead of `Null`.

Comment: I think they need `MIN(Nz(Assistant.[AS-Nice], 0))` as well.

Comment: Great answer, I'll add that if there are more "INNER" need to be replaced in a single query in some cases it is correct to replace with "RIGHT" instead of "LEFT".